# Confusion regarding fragments and its usage

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am looking at fragments and its usage in Android. I am however getting confused as how do fragments work for all the different Android versions. What i mean is that we have this `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` for versions < `Honeycomb` and the `fragment` itself for `Honeycomb` and up. My question is that how does using either one of them affect the application in terms of efficieny and performance beside the backward compatibility. Also i keep seeing that the `xml` layout changes quite a bit depending on the support package that we use . Some have `<fragment>`, some have `<fragmentActivity>`, etc. How to know what is supposed to be used in the xml?

If someone can explain me in simple terms on how to go about using the fragment in different ways it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first question there isn't any performance or efficiency issues with using either one of them beside the backward compatibility that you just mentioned.

For fragments that were added for API 11 and above there are three main classes:

```
android.app.Fragment
```

The base class for all fragment definitions

```
android.app.FragmentManager
```

The class for interacting with fragment objects inside an activity

```
android.app.FragmentTransaction
```

The class for performing an atomic set of fragment operations

And for fragments that were added for API 11 and below are:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

The base class for all activities using compatibility-based fragment (and loader) features

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

The base class for all fragment definitions

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
```

The class for interacting with fragment objects inside an activity

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
```

The class for performing an atomic set of fragment operations

If you are using the v4 support library then you need to make sure that you extend `FragmentActivity` by importing the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` and then in the xml you need to have a `<fragment>` tag with an `android:name` property where you define the complete class name.

More info: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html